# Magento 2 : Unable to change product status after programmatic import

Tags: magento2

I am **importing** my product **programmatically** , the product status is set by default to **disabled** via this code

`$product =$productFactory->create()->load($_product->getIdBySku($row["model"]));
$product->setStatus(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
$product->save();`

Now I need to **enable products manually** from dashboard but it is not changing, neither in bulk nor individually.

P.S : I have updated indexers and cleared cache.

P.S 2 : changing status programmatically works fine.

Please Help.

Comment: Can you check max  input var value?

Comment: it is set to the max value my hosting allows (max_input_vars =20000)

Comment: check your product after changing store view.

Comment: check your permissions once, also check if you get any logs? Try to create a product and check if it getting created? Check the server space if it is OK.

Comment: Check your store view and make sure you are updating the changes to the required store view

Comment: @LAW permissions,server space and product creation are perfectly fine, Ihave a dought that he problem is related to how the status is set (Status::STATUS_DISABLED) but I can't tell what might solve it.. Anyway thank you for you contribution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved!

**Changed 'status' attribute scope to 'Global'** this worked perfectly for me.

Please note that my website has a single store, this solution might not work for multiple store websites.

Comment: Thnk q For Save my Day... :)